# Convert SQL query / loop into PDO

Tags: loops, pdo, foreach

I am trying to get the PDO results displayed in a table via a loop. However presently It is just displaying a white page. Any suggestions to what is missing? or why the page is blank?

```
<?php

try {  $conn = new PDO("pgsql:host=localhost port=5432 dbname=riverflies_gis", "opengeo", "opengeo");
 echo "PDO connection object created";
 echo "<br>";
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
  echo $e->getMessage();
}

  $sql  = "SELECT admin_name, adminuser_id, group_id FROM adminuser_tbl";
  $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
  $stmt->execute();
  $data = $stmt->fetchAll();
?>

        <table border='1' cellpadding='10'>
        <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>adminuser</th>
        <th>group_id</th>
        <th></th>
       </tr>

<?php foreach ($data as $row): ?>
<tr>
<td><?=$row['adminuser_id']?></td>
<td><?=$row['admin_name']?></td>
<td><?=$row['group_id']?></td>
</tr>
<?php endforeach ?>
</table>
```

Comment: What's the problem you're having specifically?

Comment: I am just stuck with how I get the info in the PDO query to loop like the first example?

Comment: The `foreach` should be just replacing the `while` loop but there is no `$stmt->fetch()` call. I see there's two different SQL queries in play here for some reason?

Comment: There was a typo in my code. Though you need to learn to peek into server **error_log**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please **never** mix **database** operations with **HTML** output.

PDO is especially good for it. Get your data first:

```
$sql  = "SELECT admin_name, adminuser_id, group_id FROM adminuser_tbl";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
$data = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

and then output it in a **template**:

```
<table border='1' cellpadding='10'>
 <tr>
  <th>ID</th>
  <th>First Name</th>
  <th>Last Name</th>
  <th></th>
  <th></th>
 </tr>
<? foreach ($data as $row): ?>
 <tr>
  <td><?=$row['id']?></td>
  <td><?=$row['firstname']?></td>
  and so on
 </tr>
<? endforeach ?>
</table>
```

see how nice and clean your output code can be

Comment: Yeh looks a lot cleaner than the tutorial I was following.

Comment: It doesnt seem to load, do i need the php with the opening ? tags

Comment: you need to close your PHP before starting HTML of course. Or incluse a template as a separate file